# How to Implement a Request - Reply scenario using Spring jmsTemplate

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

We use JmsTemplate to send PCF commands to an MQ Queue manager admin queue.

We need this in order to switch on a QUEUE DEPT triggering on a bunch of queues. This is because after firing up the QUEUE DEPT trigger MQ manager turns off the triggering on that queue.

I know that messaging processing should by its nature be an asynchronous thing. However in this particular case it would make sense to wait for a response back informing the caller of whether the trigger was switched back on or not.

By looking at the JmsTemplate API I could not spot anywhere something like this. Did I miss anything or it is not possible to achieve a functionality like the one described by javax.jms.QueueRequestor.request(Message message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, `JmsTemplate` does not offer such feature. You can look at [SPR-332](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-3332) for the whole history.

The last comment has [a link to a project](https://github.com/snicoll/scratches/tree/master/jms-request-reply) that shows how you can very easily implement that with Spring Integration.

Comment: A pity you have to introduce a new project dependency just to address a simple thing like this natively supported by JMS specifications.

As a spring enthusiastic I can admit I felt a bit left down.

Comment: Hi Julian. What is natively supported by the JMS spec? If it was, there's nothing we would have to do on our side, isn't it? Back to your comment, I understand the frustration but it would be as equally frustrated to provide a solution that only works in a limited range of use case (timeout, means to collect the response, number of replies, etc).

Comment: javax.jms.QueueRequestor provides this request reply functionality. I would have expected JmsTemplate would have wrapped it just to address the concerns you were pointed to like timeout, etc.